# How do I have a custom typeface option for FBIA (Facebook Instant Article) styles?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I have been managing many facebook pages and one of the pages previously implemented by an ex-developer (who cannot be contacted anymore) has the option to choose a custom typeface or font for the text being displayed on FBIA. Has anyone come across the same issue and resolved it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that feature is available only to certain accounts (I would guess very large accounts) that have a ["Direct Support"](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-instant-articles-sdk-php/issues/216) option on their Instant Articles settings page like this:

[image: Direct Support Option]

For the rest of us it seems this is not an option as of yet - as stated by Facebook support ["Sorry custom fonts are not available to the public at the moment."](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1121715027891936/)